# Facing problem while converting an SQL query to Laravel query using Query builder

Tags: sql, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-query-builder

The SQL query which I am converting is this.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Meetings Offered' AS Source,
             'Meetings Chosen' AS Destination,
             COUNT(1) AS value,
             DATE (created_at) AS DATE
      FROM typeform_contacts
      WHERE client_signed = 1
      GROUP BY DATE (created_at)
      UNION
      SELECT 'Meetings Chosen' AS Source,
             '4A OR 4B' AS Destination,
             COUNT(1) AS Value,
             DATE (created_at) AS DATE
      FROM lawyer_opportunity_meetings
      WHERE contact_type = 'typeform'
      GROUP BY DATE (created_at)
      UNION
      SELECT '4A OR 4B' AS Source,
             '4B Get L times' AS Destination,
             COUNT(1) AS Value,
             DATE (date_added) AS DATE
      FROM dripfeed_targets
      WHERE feed_id in(360, 361)
      GROUP BY DATE (date_added)
      UNION
      SELECT '4B Get L times' AS Source,
             '4C - Meeting Set' AS Destination,
             COUNT(1) AS Value,
             DATE (date_added) AS DATE
      FROM dripfeed_targets
      WHERE feed_id in(361)
      GROUP BY DATE (date_added)
      UNION
      SELECT '4C - Meeting Set' AS Source,
             '4D Follow up' AS Destination,
             COUNT(1) AS Value,
             DATE (date_added) AS DATE
      FROM dripfeed_targets
      WHERE feed_id in(362)
      GROUP BY DATE (date_added)
      UNION
      SELECT '4D Follow up' AS Source,
             '' AS Destination,
             COUNT(1) AS Value,
             DATE (date_added) AS DATE
      FROM dripfeed_targets
      WHERE feed_id in(363)
      GROUP BY DATE (date_added)
) AS TEMP 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2023-1-1' AND '2023-1-30'
```

I have tried to convert it using query builder in the following manner :

```
public function meetingSankey() {
        $returnArray = array();
        $result = DB::query()->fromSub(
            DB::table('typeform_contacts')
            ->selectRaw("'Meetings Offered' AS Source, 'Meetings Chosen' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS value, DATE(created_at) AS DATE")
            ->where('client_signed', 1)
            ->groupByRaw('DATE(created_at)')
    
            ->union(
                    DB::table('lawyer_opportunity_meetings')
                    ->selectRaw("'Meetings Chosen' AS Source, '4A OR 4B' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(created_at) AS DATE")
                    ->where('contact_type', 'typeform')
                    ->groupByRaw('DATE(created_at)')
                )
    
            ->union(
                    DB::table('dripfeed_targets')
                    ->selectRaw("'4A OR 4B' AS Source, '4B Get L times' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE")
                    ->whereIn('feed_id', [360, 361])
                    ->groupByRaw('DATE(date_added)')
                )
    
            ->union(
                    DB::table('dripfeed_targets')
                    ->selectRaw("'4B Get L times' AS Source, '4C - Meeting Set' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE")
                    ->whereIn('feed_id', [361])
                    ->groupByRaw('DATE(date_added)')
                )
    
            ->union(
                    DB::table('dripfeed_targets')
                    ->selectRaw("'4C - Meeting Set' AS Source, '4D Follow up' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE")
                    ->whereIn('feed_id', [362])
                    ->groupByRaw('DATE(date_added)')
                )
    
            ->union(
                    DB::table('dripfeed_targets')
                    ->selectRaw("'4D Follow up' AS Source, '' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE")
                    ->whereIn('feed_id', [363])
                    ->groupByRaw('DATE(date_added)')
                ), 'temp')
            ->whereBetween('DATE', [Carbon::create(2023,1,1,0)->toDateTimeString(), Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()])->get();

        $returnArray['data'] = $result;
        $returnArray['status'] = "success";

        return response()->json($returnArray, 200);
    }
```

Now when I am running this code it shows the following error; although the column client_signed exist in the table typeform_contacts:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "client_signed" does not exist
LINE 1: ...reated_at) AS DATE from "typeform_contacts" where "client_si...
                                                             ^ (SQL: select * from ((select 'Meetings Offered' AS Source, 'Meetings Chosen' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS value, DATE(created_at) AS DATE from "typeform_contacts" where "client_signed" = 1 group by DATE(created_at)) union (select 'Meetings Chosen' AS Source, '4A OR 4B' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(created_at) AS DATE from "lawyer_opportunity_meetings" where "contact_type" = typeform group by DATE(created_at)) union (select '4A OR 4B' AS Source, '4B Get L times' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE from "dripfeed_targets" where "feed_id" in (360, 361) group by DATE(date_added)) union (select '4B Get L times' AS Source, '4C - Meeting Set' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE from "dripfeed_targets" where "feed_id" in (361) group by DATE(date_added)) union (select '4C - Meeting Set' AS Source, '4D Follow up' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE from "dripfeed_targets" where "feed_id" in (362) group by DATE(date_added)) union (select '4D Follow up' AS Source, '' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE from "dripfeed_targets" where "feed_id" in (363) group by DATE(date_added))) as "temp" where "DATE" between 2023-01-01 00:00:00 and 2023-01-31 18:26:32) in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/multitenant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 671
```

When I am separately executing the query which is getting built from the query builder:

```
select * from (select 'Meetings Offered' AS Source, 'Meetings Chosen' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS value, DATE(created_at) AS DATE from "typeform_contacts" where "client_signed" = 1 group by DATE(created_at) 
               union (select 'Meetings Chosen' AS Source, '4A OR 4B' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(created_at) AS DATE from "lawyer_opportunity_meetings" where "contact_type" = typeform group by DATE(created_at)) 
               union (select '4A OR 4B' AS Source, '4B Get L times' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE from "dripfeed_targets" where "feed_id" in (360, 361) group by DATE(date_added)) 
               union (select '4B Get L times' AS Source, '4C - Meeting Set' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE from "dripfeed_targets" where "feed_id" in (361) group by DATE(date_added)) 
               union (select '4C - Meeting Set' AS Source, '4D Follow up' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE from "dripfeed_targets" where "feed_id" in (362) group by DATE(date_added)) 
               union (select '4D Follow up' AS Source, '' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE from "dripfeed_targets" where "feed_id" in (363) group by DATE(date_added)) as "temp" )
               where "DATE" between '2023-01-01 00:00:00' and '2023-01-31 18:12:57';
```

It throws an error as shown below:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 6: ...ere "feed_id" in (363) group by DATE(date_added)) as "temp" ...
```

Kindly suggest if possible where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would move all your inner query to a variable and then do a from fromSub.

```
 $result = DB::table('typeform_contacts')
        ->selectRaw("'Meetings Offered' AS Source, 'Meetings Chosen' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS value, DATE(created_at) AS DATE")
        ->where('client_signed', 1)
        ->groupByRaw('DATE(created_at)')

        ->union(
                DB::table('lawyer_opportunity_meetings')
                ->selectRaw("'Meetings Chosen' AS Source, '4A OR 4B' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(created_at) AS DATE")
                ->where('contact_type', 'typeform')
                ->groupByRaw('DATE(created_at)')
            )

        ->union(
                DB::table('dripfeed_targets')
                ->selectRaw("'4A OR 4B' AS Source, '4B Get L times' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE")
                ->whereIn('feed_id', [360, 361])
                ->groupByRaw('DATE(date_added)')
            )

        ->union(
                DB::table('dripfeed_targets')
                ->selectRaw("'4B Get L times' AS Source, '4C - Meeting Set' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE")
                ->whereIn('feed_id', [361])
                ->groupByRaw('DATE(date_added)')
            )

        ->union(
                DB::table('dripfeed_targets')
                ->selectRaw("'4C - Meeting Set' AS Source, '4D Follow up' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE")
                ->whereIn('feed_id', [362])
                ->groupByRaw('DATE(date_added)')
            )

        ->union(
                DB::table('dripfeed_targets')
                ->selectRaw("'4D Follow up' AS Source, '' AS Destination, COUNT(1) AS Value, DATE(date_added) AS DATE")
                ->whereIn('feed_id', [363])
                ->groupByRaw('DATE(date_added)')
            ), 'temp')
        ;

$newResult = DB::query()->fromSub($result, 'temp')->whereBetween('DATE', [Carbon::create(2023,1,1,0)->toDateTimeString(), Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()])->get();
```

Comment: Okay will try this approach; and inform you